# Ubuntu disk partioning issue: not enough space

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, disk

I have a laptop with a 640 HDD and a 20GB SSD. I have installed the OS in the SSD and want to use the HDD to store large files like software, pictures, videos, etc.

I installed VirtualBox, but after a few minutes I receive an error message telling me there is not enough space on the disk.

This is the output from `df`:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1             19479720  11169508   7333012  61% /
none                   1332276       272   1332004   1% /dev
none                   1340408       144   1340264   1% /dev/shm
none                   1340408       192   1340216   1% /var/run
none                   1340408         0   1340408   0% /var/lock
none                   1340408         0   1340408   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda5              9733688    352948   8892500   4% /boot
/dev/sda1            243853300  10379904 221266396   5% /home
```

Extra information:

```
root@bt:~# grep defaultMachineFolder ~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
    <SystemProperties defaultMachineFolder="/root/VirtualBox VMs" defaultHardDiskFormat="VDI" VRDEAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" webServiceAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" LogHistoryCount="3"/>
```

@netcoder    this means if i will try to install virtualbox it will get installed in the root partition ? 
@netcoder    i got it  now    lol    i didnt slept for 2 days   thats why i feel stupid right now lol     . anyways  thx for helping    .

Comment: Install the OS on the SSD with mountpoint `/`, add a mountpoint `/home` for the 640 HDD.

Comment: thanks for reply netcoder .  i tried to do the same way you said , but  i dont know what happend .  i installed Virtual Box  after few minutes i saw a message on my Desktop saying " not enough space "  any suggestions  pls ? by the way in my /home  i have 250 GB free

Comment: Please post the output of `df` (by editing your question).

Comment: Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1             19479720  11169508   7333012  61% /
none                   1332276       272   1332004   1% /dev
none                   1340408       144   1340264   1% /dev/shm
none                   1340408       192   1340216   1% /var/run
none                   1340408         0   1340408   0% /var/lock
none                   1340408         0   1340408   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda5              9733688    352948   8892500   4% /boot
/dev/sda1            243853300  10379904 221266396   5% /home

Comment: Don't post this in a comment, edit your question, and format it correctly. Also, what's the output if you run `grep defaultMachineFolder ~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running VirtualBox as root, which causes it to store disk images and virtual machines in `/root`, which is part of the `/` filesystem, which is your 20GB SSD that has ~7GB of free space.

The easy solution is: **don't run it as root, run it as your own user.** There is no advantage I know of in running VirtualBox as root.